# How to persist Firebase UserCredential object, so can use UserCredential.sendEmailVerification() function

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-native-firebase

Firebase `UserCredential` object is generated when user logs in.

I want to use the function `UserCredential.sendEmailVerification()` to generate email to user if they have not previously verified their email address.....however I do not want to do this as soon as user has logged in.
Instead I want to wait until they want to unlock some further functionality in the app....and only then do I want to send the verification email by running the `UserCredential.sendEmailVerification()` function.

Problem is....how do I persist the `UserCredential` object so that I have access to the sendEmailVerification() function everywhere in the app?

Is it possible to store as state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the signed in user at any time by using the code from the first snippet in the documentation on [getting the current user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user):

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    if (!user.emailVerified) {
      user.sendEmailVerification();
    }
  }
});
```